# Couldn't find that process type (web) - Procfile issue?

Tags: heroku, scaling, procfile

When I run "heroku ps:scale web=1" I get this error: Couldn't find that process type (web).
My procfile is capitalized, it doesn't have any extensions, and it has this line in it: web:gunicorn app:app

I've tried adding a space after web but no luck, please help

Its not scaling, it just keeps giving me that error